# Have all the parts to my program, except implementing DynamicModule and InputField

Tags: plotting, manipulate, dynamic, inputfield

I've posted before and I think (hopefully) I'm almost done. I want to make a program that models a cantilever bending on a box given parameters, like this:

[image]

I calculated the parametric equations (given a rotation) as:

```
x*Cos[θ] - (P*x^2)/(6*C*D) (3 F + x) Sin[θ]
x*Sin[θ] + (P*x^2)/(6*C*D) (3 F + x) Cos[θ]
```

where the first equation is x-coor and the second is y-coor. I confusingly used x as the parameter in the parametric equations.

```
B = 2;
Manipulate[Show[
  {Graphics[{Opacity[0.5], Red,
     Rectangle[{1, 0}, {2, 1}]},
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 2}, {-3, 3}}, Axes -> True,
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}],
   ParametricPlot[{x*Cos[θ] - (P*x^2)/(
       6*C*D) (3 F + x) Sin[θ], 
     x*Sin[θ] + (P*x^2)/(6*C*D) (3 F + x) Cos[θ] + 
      G}, {x, 0, B}, Axes -> True]}],
 {P, 0, 1},
 {{C, 1}, 0, 10},
 {{D, 1}, 0, 10},
 {F, 0, 10},
 {{θ, 0}, -2 π, 2 π},
 {{G, 0} , -3, 3},
 SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

[image]

Instead of slide bars, I want them to be InputFields. Further, I want adjustment of the Y axis to touch the corner of the box to be dynamic.

To find the parameter where the cantilever touches the box (corner at coordinates (a,b),

```
Solve[a == x*Cos[θ] - (P*x^2)/(6*C*D) (3 F + x) Sin[θ]] = c
```

Then, to find the needed adjustment to the y-component,

```
c*Sin[θ] + (P*c^2)/(6*C*D) (3 F + c) Cos[θ] -b = d
```

my idea is that this d is now the adjustment to the y-component of the parametric equation above. If this could be made dynamic, it would be great. I tried modifying the example application code from Wolfram.com to just output the values

```
DynamicModule[{a = 0, b = 0}, Deploy[Style[
       Panel[Grid[
         Transpose[{{Style["right side x-coor", Red], 
            Style["right side y-coor", Red],
            "value of x'", "y-shift"},
           {InputField[Dynamic[a], Number], 
            InputField[Dynamic[b], Number],
            InputField[
             Dynamic[
              Solve[a == x*Cos[θ] - (P*x^2)/(6*C*D) (3 F + x) Sin[θ]] = c],Enabled -> False], 
            InputField[
             Dynamic[
              c*Sin[θ] + (P*c^2)/(6*C*D) (3 F + c) Cos[θ] - b,Enabled -> False]}}],Alignment -> Right], ImageMargins -> 10, DefaultOptions -> {InputField -> {ContinuousAction -> True, FieldSize -> {{5, 30}, {1, Infinity}}}}]]]]
```

Obviously, it didn't work. Further, my attempts to make the plot dynamic did not work either. Perhaps I should be using Manipulate instead of Dynamic? I'm not sure. In either case, if someone could help me figure out how to get Dynamic to work with just outputting numbers and then how to get my plot inside as well (mostly the second part), that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Go to the docs for [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) and search for `InputField`.  Several alternatives are described.

Comment: Your `DynamicModule` code has unmatched delimiters (`[`, `{`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the Manipulate documentation, you can change your sliders to input fields by going from control {x,0,10} to {x,0}.

```
B = 2;
Manipulate[
 Show[{Graphics[{Opacity[0.5], Red, Rectangle[{1, 0}, {2, 1}]}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 2}, {-3, 3}}, Axes -> True, 
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}], 
   ParametricPlot[{x*
       Cos[\[Theta]] - (P*x^2)/(6*C*D) (3 F + x) Sin[\[Theta]], 
     x*Sin[\[Theta]] + (P*x^2)/(6*C*D) (3 F + x) Cos[\[Theta]] + 
      G}, {x, 0, B}, Axes -> True]}], {P, 0}, {C, 1}, {D, 1}, {F, 
  0}, {\[Theta], 0}, {G, 0}, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

Comment: I didn't have the reputation to say this above, but I do not entirely understand your second question! Clarifying it would be appreciated.